# How to ignore XML declaration differences with XmlUnit?

Tags: xmlunit, xmlunit-2

How can I configure XmlUnit.Net to ignore the XML declaration when comparing two documents?

Assume I have the following control document:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a><amount>1</amount></a>
```

Which I want to compare with:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<a><amount>1</amount></a>
```

The comparison should result in no differences.

My expectation would be that using a NodeFilter like so should work, but it doesn't:

```cs
var diff = DiffBuilder.Compare(control)
    .WithTest(test)
    .WithNodeFilter(n => n.NodeType != XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
    .Build();

diff.Differences.Count().Should().Be(0);
```

The assertion fails with two differences - one for the encoding (different casing) and another for the standalone attribute. I'm not interested in any.

Whether I say `n.NodeType != XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration` or `n.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration` makes no difference.

I am using XMLUnit.Core v2.5.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NodeFilter` only applies to nodes that are children of other nodes (returned by `XmlNode.ChildNodes`). Unfortunately this is not the case for the document type declaration, which probably is a bug.

In your case you want to tweak the `DifferenceEvaluator` and downgrade the differences you are not interested in. Something like

```
DifferenceEvaluators.Chain(DifferenceEvaluators.Default,
    DifferenceEvaluators.DowngradeDifferencesToEqual(ComparisonType.XML_STANDALONE, ComparisonType.XML_ENCODING))
```

would swallow the differences.

Maybe you don't want to just count the differences but also look at their severity. The difference in encoding would be a "similar" difference, while the different values of standalone are critical.

Comment: Using the evaluator you describe solves the problem for me. Will note the severity differences. Thank you for your dedication to XmlUnit, appreciated!

Comment: you're welcome. I've opened an issue for `NodeFilter` and document types, it is going to be fixed in the next release.

Comment: I see that you added a commit for this: https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit/commit/4f5ce2c86f45f82c2bbee96c715fd271a32faab2

How to use it though?